# streaming audio from mic across websocket. I can see the data being sent but cannot hear it on the receiving client side

Tags: audio, audiocontext

I'm trying to broadcast captured mic audio across a websocket. I can see the buffer array is being sent, and the array has actual valid data but the receiving client side cannot hear it. I'm pretty sure my playback function is correct, because I can generate white noise by filling an array with random numbers and using the playback function to hear it. I'm thinking maybe the audio it's broadcasting is too quiet to hear, because the numbers generated in the array are seem to mostly be in the .000### range. Any ideas? Capturing mic audio and broadcasting it seems to be over complicated... :/

```
 //broadcasting side 
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true,video: false}) // request cam
        .then(stream => {
         vid.srcObject = stream;
         context = new AudioContext();
         var source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
         var processor = context.createScriptProcessor(1024, 2, 2);
         source.connect(processor);
         processor.connect(context.destination);

         processor.onaudioprocess = function(e) {
           audiodata = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(1);
          socket.send(JSON.stringify({sound: audiodata, to: to, from: '$username', text:''}));
         };
         return vid.play(); // returns a Promise
       });



//receiving side object to array 

       if(typeof (message.sound) != "undefined"){
         //$('#video_stream_btn').trigger('click');
          var json_sound = message.sound;
          var array_sound = [];
          for(var i in json_sound){
            array_sound.push([i, json_sound [i]]);
          }
         if(typeof(context) == 'undefined'){
           context = new AudioContext();
         }
         play_sound(array_sound, context);
         return;
       }


// receiving side play sound function 

    function play_sound(raw,context){

        //alert(raw.length);
        var audioBuffer = context.createBuffer(1, raw.length, context.sampleRate);
        audioBuffer.getChannelData(0).set(raw);
        var source = context.createBufferSource();
        source.buffer = audioBuffer;
        source.connect(context.destination);
        source.start(0);

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone out there trying to figure this out. I ended up encoding it to an int16array, then sent it across the socket, where the client encoded it back into a float32 array and passed it to the play_sound function. I basically just stole a bunch of stuff off stackoverflow and faked it until I made it, cause I'm not that smart :)

capturing mic and converting to int16array, then sending it across the socket

```
 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: {sampleSize: 16, channelCount: 2},video: true}) // request cam
        .then(stream => {
         vid.srcObject = stream; // don't use createObjectURL(MediaStream)
         context = new AudioContext();
         var source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
         var processor = context.createScriptProcessor(1024, 2, 2);
         source.connect(processor);
         processor.connect(context.destination);

         processor.onaudioprocess = function(e) {
          // Do something with the data, i.e Convert this to WAV
          audiodata = new Int16Array(convertFloat32ToInt16(e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0)));
          console.log(audiodata);
          socket.send(JSON.stringify({sound: audiodata, to: to, from: '$username', text:''}));

         };
         return vid.play(); // returns a Promise
       });
```

relevant function for converting captured mic to int16array:

```
function convertFloat32ToInt16(buffer){
          l = buffer.length;
          buf = new Int16Array(l);

      while (l--)
      {
         buf[l] = Math.min(1, buffer[l])*0x7FFF;
      }

      return buf.buffer;

  }
```

receiving client side json object to int16array, then int16array back to float32array:

```
if(typeof (message.sound) != "undefined"){
         //$('#video_stream_btn').trigger('click');
          //var json_sound = message.sound;


         if(typeof(context) == 'undefined'){
           context = new AudioContext();
         }
         sound_array = [];
         for (i in message.sound)
         {
            sound_array[i] = (message.sound [i]);
         }

        //sound_array16 = new Int16Array(sound_array);
        sound_array32 = int16ToFloat32(sound_array);
         play_sound(sound_array32, context);
         return;
       }
```

relevant receiving side int16array to float32array function:

```
    function int16ToFloat32(inputArray) {

        let int16arr = new Int16Array(inputArray)
        var output = new Float32Array(int16arr.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < int16arr.length; i++) {
            var int = int16arr[i];
            var float = (int >= 0x8000) ? -(0x10000 - int) / 0x8000 : int / 0x7FFF;
            output[i] = float;
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement